# LoginType field shows length 1 but retrieves length greater than 1

Tags: soap-api, sobject, fields

I am trying to query AuthSession object where the loginType field shows the length 1 but the length is actually greater than 1.

Sample:

```
Id ID 18
UsersId ID 18
CreatedDate dateTime 0
LastModifiedDate dateTime 0
NumSecondsValid _int 0
UserType string 40
SourceIp string 39
LoginType string 1
SessionType string 40
SessionSecurityLevel string 40
LogoutUrl string 1500
ParentId ID 18
LoginHistoryId ID 18
```

Querying through DevConsole returned the values:

```
Application 
Other Apex API 
Partner Product 
Sync 
Excel Integration 
Apex Office Toolkit 
Other Apex API 
Salesforce.com Website 
Remote Access Client 
Remote Access 2.0 
AppStore 
Chatter Communities External User
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've confirmed your findings. There appears to be something wrong with the [AuthSession](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_authsession.htm).LoginType metadata.

It is listed as a picklist, but has no picklistValues defined and a length of 1. Compare it to something like UserType that has a defined length of 40 and a defined list of 7 picklistValues PicklistEntry records.

Oddly, SessionType is a picklist with a defined length, but is also missing the defined picklistValues.

As a pure guess, I'd say something internal to Salesforce is being coerced to appear in the API as the AuthSession. As part of that process they are manipulating the data to fit into the allowed API metadata and have incorrectly mapped the LoginType field.

The [Understanding User Session Information](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=security_user_session_info.htm&siteLang=en_US) documentation for the equivalent UI page gives possible values as including (plus the one for API logins):

1. Application
2. SAML
3. Portal
4. Other Apex API

If you are feeling particularly keen you could raise this as a bug in the [developer forum](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/#!/feedtype=RECENT&criteria=ALLQUESTIONS).